# how to call trigger change on change event javascript

Tags: javascript, select

i have a checkbox where `if isChecked = 1` a select element will show up then from select you can choose from the option. then `if isChecked = 0` select element hide and supposedly to reset the selected option to its default option.

scenario i checked the input box. 
    then the select element show up then i select a room.
    then i changed my mind so i unchecked the inputbox.
    what supposed to happen is to change the selected option to its default option.
    but when i re-checked the input box the option i selected still tag as selected option.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" name="isChecked"><span>isChecked </span>
</div> 

 <div class="form-group technical">
    <label>Rooms</label>
    <select class="form-control technicalrooms" name="technicalrooms">
      <option selected disabled>Select Room</option>
      <option value="Function Room">Function Room</option>
      <option value="Meeting Room">Meeting Room</option>
    </select>  
  </div>
```

and here is my code.

```
$('.technical').hide();
$('[name="isChecked"]').on('change', function () {
    var val = ($(this).is(':checked') == true) ? 1 : 0;

    if(val == 1){
          $(".technical").show();
    }else{
          $(".technical").hide();

          $(".technicalrooms option:first").trigger('change');
    }
})
```

Comment: Set the value of the `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the options `checked` property  to `true` not trigger `change`. Triggering `change` will only execute any handlers bound to it, not affect its state.

```
$(".technicalrooms option:first").prop('selected', true);
```

working demo

```js
$('.technical').hide();

$('[name="isChecked"]').on('change', function () {
    var val = ($(this).is(':checked') == true) ? 1 : 0;

    if(val == 1){
          $(".technical").show();
    }else{
          $(".technical").hide();
          var trooms = $(".technicalrooms');
          $("option:first", trooms).prop('selected', true);
          trooms.trigger('change');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" name="isChecked"><span>isChecked </span>
</div> 

 <div class="form-group technical">
    <label>Rooms</label>
    <select class="form-control technicalrooms" name="technicalrooms">
      <option selected disabled>Select Room</option>
      <option value="Function Room">Function Room</option>
      <option value="Meeting Room">Meeting Room</option>
    </select>  
  </div>
```

Comment: oohh i see.. last question im actually using select2 plugin and even though the first option is selected the option that is being displayed is the one i previously selected..

Comment: @LionSmith then you will need to **also** trigger the `change` event but on the `#technicalrooms` element, not the `option`. (*updated code*)

Comment: thank you so much... it works. you're such a great help.